# Can't call INPauseWorkoutIntent without home button

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

I have implemented INPauseWorkoutIntent, INStartWorkoutIntent or INResumeWorkoutIntent in my app in IOS 12 and XCode 10. I can use the commands correctly with using home button to open Siri but what I need is Hand off. I mean, I just want to say "Pause workout" and it should pause. I also don't want to use watch. How to achieve that, what am I missing?

Note: `- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent` not called anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have implemented resolve, confirm, and handler functions comforting to respective protocols.

I just check response code for workout and they have .continueInApp response code.
That being said, I believe you can pass response with code .continueInApp and save whatever parameters you have to use in UserActivity in handler's completion. UserAcitivity will be passed to application: continueUserActivity function in AppDelegate; so you can pause it from there.

If handlerForIntent is not called, then I believe intent is not understood by Siri

Comment: handlerForIntent is not called at all. what might be the reason why its not called?

Comment: In Info.plist, did you define which Intents are used in IntentExtension's plist? You have to define all the Intent you use in plist's NSExtension.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_app_extension